# Return two separate arrays from an object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I need to complete the keysAndValues function so that it takes an object and returns the keys and values as separate arrays. For example:

```
keysAndValues({k: 11, l: 12, m: 13}) // should return [['k', 'l', 'm'], [11, 12, 13]]
```

I have already tried: http://jsfiddle.net/marcusdei/ppfh5fpa/4/

Comment: Object.keys(youobj) for getting keys

Comment: And what's wrong with your fiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```js
function keyValues(obj, keys){
 return [keys = Object.keys(obj), keys.map(function(k){return obj[k]})]
}

var result = keyValues({k: 11, l: 12, m: 13});

document.write(JSON.stringify(result))
```

Comment: this did not return two arrays

Comment: @Andy If he will use more than 10,000 fields in a object, yes

Comment: Well... he might :) @wZVanG.

Comment: Using the argument list as a way to hide a variable declaration is sort of questionable. Also, AFAIK you are not absolutely guaranteed that the two elements of the array will be evaluated in order, so in theory, the second element could be evaluated before the first, so `keys` would be undefined.

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```js
function keysAndValues(data){
    var keys = Object.keys(data),
        values = keys.map(function (key) {
            return data[key];
        });
    
    return [keys, values]; 
}

console.log(keysAndValues({k: 11, l: 12, m: 13}));
```

> [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) - The Object.keys() method returns an array of a given
>   object's own enumerable properties
>
> [`.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) - The map() method creates a new array with the results of
>   calling a provided function on every element in this array.

**Update**

There is new method `.values` which was added to `Object`,

```js
function keysAndValues(data){
  return [Object.keys(data), Object.values(data)]; 
}

console.log(keysAndValues({k: 11, l: 12, m: 13}));
```

> [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) - the method returns an array of a given object's own enumerable property values, in the same order as that provided by a `for...in` loop

Answer (score 0):

The old-fashioned way, defining two arrays and pushing the keys and values into them.

```
function keysAndValues(obj) {
    var keys = [], values = [];
    for (var p in obj) {
        keys.push(p);
        values.push(obj[p]);
    }
    return [keys, values];
}
```

[JSPerf says this has the better performance by far](http://jsperf.com/keysandvaluesaw).

Answer (score 0):

```js
function keysAndValues(obj) {
    var keys = [];
    var value = [];
    for (key in obj) {
        keys.push(key);
        value.push(obj[key]);
    }
    return [keys,value]

}
console.log(keysAndValues({
    k: 11,
    l: 12,
    m: 13
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

[Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) gets you halfway there, returning an array of key-value` pairs.

Example:

```
obj = { k: 11, l: 12, m: 13 }
Object.entries(obj); // [["k", 11], ["l", 12], ["m", 13]]
```

From here you can reduce this array into separate arrays by pushing the keys into one array and the values into the other.

```js
const keysAndValues = (obj) =>
  Object.entries(obj).reduce(
    ([keys, values], [key, value]) => [keys.concat(key), values.concat(value)],
    [[], []]
  );

const res = keysAndValues({ k: 11, l: 12, m: 13 });

console.log(JSON.stringify(res)); // [["k", "l", "m"], [11, 12, 13]]
```